# Convert SQL OPENXML to XML Nodes Value

Tags: xml, c#

Can anyone help with converting the following from OPENXML to Node

```
protected virtual void ApplySqlXmlSetupSql()
{
  if (!this.query.HasFilterBySectionList && this.query.IgnorePermissions && !this.query.HasExcludeSectionList)
    return;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("<xml>");
  if (this.query.HasFilterBySectionList || !this.query.IgnorePermissions)
    this.GetSectionIDXml(sb);
  if (this.query.HasExcludeSectionList)
    this.GetExcludeSectionIDXml(sb);
  sb.Append("</xml>");
  this.sb.Append("DECLARE @iXml int\n").Append("DECLARE @sectionIDs table (sectionID int not null primary key)\n").Append("DECLARE @excludeSectionIDs table (sectionID int not null primary key)\n").Append("EXECUTE [master].[dbo].[sp_xml_preparedocument] @iXml OUTPUT, ").Append("N'").Append(sb.ToString()).Append("'").Append("\n").Append("set nocount on\n");
  if (this.query.HasFilterBySectionList || !this.query.IgnorePermissions)
    this.sb.Append("insert into @sectionIDs ").Append("SELECT a.sectionID FROM ").Append("OPENXML(@iXml, '/xml/SectionIDs/i', 2) ").Append("WITH ( sectionID int '.' ) AS a\n");
  if (this.query.HasExcludeSectionList)
    this.sb.Append("insert into @excludeSectionIDs ").Append("SELECT a.sectionID FROM ").Append("OPENXML(@iXml, '/xml/ExcludeSectionIDs/i', 2) ").Append("WITH ( sectionID int '.' ) AS a\n");
  this.sb.Append("set nocount off\n").Append("EXECUTE [master].[dbo].[sp_xml_removedocument] @iXml\n").Append("\n");
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186918.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188282.aspx

UPDATE

Basically the sql boils down to:

```
DECLARE @iXml int
DECLARE @sectionIDs table (sectionID int not null primary key)
DECLARE @excludeSectionIDs table (sectionID int not null primary key)
EXECUTE [master].[dbo].[sp_xml_preparedocument] @iXml OUTPUT, N''
set nocount on

insert into @sectionIDs SELECT a.sectionID FROM OPENXML(@iXml, '/xml/SectionIDs/i', 2) WITH ( sectionID int '.' ) AS a
insert into @excludeSectionIDs SELECT a.sectionID FROM OPENXML(@iXml, '/xml/ExcludeSectionIDs/i', 2) WITH ( sectionID int '.' ) AS a

set nocount off
EXECUTE [master].[dbo].[sp_xml_removedocument] @iXml
```

Comment: Welcome.  That's a lot of code to work through.  Can you reduce it to the minimal example that demonstrates your problem, then edit your question to show just that?  Preferably just the SQL rather than the surrounding method.  Some description of the expected output would help, too, with sample data.  What version & edition of SQL Server are you using?  Edit the tags to match, please.

Comment: will be a lot easier if you post sample query produced by that code, and focus specifically on "converting OPEN XML to XML Nodes Value"